# In App Purchase finished outside of an iPhone app

Tags: iphone, in-app-purchase, subscription

I am implementing an in app purchase subscription model.

Let's say I have an iPhone 3 user which starts the whole purchase process from my application and then exits the application only to continue and fill his app store credentials outside of my app until he is done with the purchase.

How can my app know that the transaction was made upon launch?
Also in case I do get this info how can I tell it is not an old purchase for an old subscription period which has already expired?

And last but not least in case the device supports multitasking and the purchase was finished while my app was in the background how will I get notified upon returning to the foreground?

Thanks

Roi

Answer (score 0):

Have you read Apple's Documentation - [In App Purchase Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/index.html)?  I believe it answers all your questions.

Comment: OK just in case anyone is interested in the answer, since the purchase was made outside of the app the app itself didn't call the finishTransaction method and therefore the app will get notifications when it is launched again about the same purchase.

Answer (score 0):

The - (void)recordTransaction:(SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction method takes care of most of your pains.

Once you properly implement this method,you would just have to check whether the inApp purchase is done.Rest is taken care of by the payment methods.

Thanks